# how to put css and javascript someplace other than under public folder

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, public

Nevermind the reason why, I know it goes against the grain of putting css under public/stylesheets and js in public/javascripts (this is a legacy Rails 2.3.5 project, I'm asking about), and there is a desire to place all js and css related to a  particular feature within it's own folder instead of spread out and mixed with the rest of the code base.

Is there a way to link to these static assets if they are not placed within the public folder?

Comment: Am i right in thinking that you want to store JS and CSS to access them outside of the public folder? One solution is to add the asset pipeline to your rails project http://pivotallabs.com/giving-rails-2-the-asset-pipeline/ and add some folder to your asset path.

Comment: is there no easier configuration file to change the load path that doesn't require asset pipeline?

Comment: I have the same question. Does someone know how to do this ?